# Is there any redis-cli cmd to know redis has replayed all the data from dump.rdb snapshot

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a requirement to dynamically turn on appendonly setting after redis replayed all the data from backup file dump.rdb. So is there any redis-cli cmd to know that redis has loaded all the data from dump.rdb snapshot?#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Redis is loading RDB files, it refuses most commands, e.g. `PING`. So you can send a `PING` command, i.e. `redis-cli ping`, to Redis. If it returns *PONG*, Redis has already loaded all data. If Redis is still loading, it returns an error reply.